# Forms builder. Error ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve the connection identifier specified

Tags: forms, oracle, builder

I have installed `Oracle 11g DB` and `10g Developers suite` (need to use forms builder).

I've made a new database called genericName and I'm trying to connect to it using `sys/myPasswordChoice/genericName` to it from Form builder.

I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve the connection identifier specified
```

I've searched the Internet for a solution and it seems that I need to modify something in one of the `.ora` files.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes even Oracle 6i can connect to 11g!!!
check $oracle_home/network/admin/tnsnames.ora. ($oracle_home is where developer suite is installed)
Add the entry manualy or use net configuration assistant gui tool. The next lines:

```
apex2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.53.2.55)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = uni11g)
    )
  )
```

describes the tns name apex2 (the one you use in forms to connect), that points to an 11g database installed in 10.53.2.55 ip with the sid uni11g. adapt them to your settings

Answer (score 0):

Often, it's a typographical error in your connexion string or in your tnsnames.ora file (general tnsnames.ora location is: $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora). More information here : [11g/ORA-12154](http://www.oracle-error.com/11g/ORA-12154.html).